# Setting limit for registration?

Tags: php, mysql, limit, registration, max

As i already tried but nodbody helped me i will try it again. I want to set a limit to 16 for people who want to register with this script can please somebody edit MY script and post it here so that i can copy paste it couse im pretty bad in coding so before i try around and get always an error plz somebody just simply post my code with the limt 16. Thank you guys it would be so great if someone do it

here is the script

```
<?php
$error_message = "";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
   $action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : '';
   $mysql_server = 'X';
   $mysql_username = 'X';
   $mysql_password = 'X';
   $mysql_database = 'X';
   $mysql_table = 'LOL';

   $success_page = 'X';
   if ($action == 'signup')
   {
      $newusername = $_POST['username'];
      $newemail = $_POST['email'];
      $newpassword = $_POST['password'];
      $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
      $newfullname = $_POST['fullname'];
      if ($newpassword != $confirmpassword)
      {
         $error_message = 'Password and Confirm Password are not the same!';
      }
      else
      if (!ereg("^[A-Za-z0-9_!@$]{1,50}$", $newusername))
      {
         $error_message = 'Team name is not valid, please check and try again!';
      }
      else
      if (!ereg("^[A-Za-z0-9_!@$]{1,50}$", $newpassword))
      {
         $error_message = 'Password is not valid, please check and try again!';
      }
      else
      if (!ereg("^.+@.+\..+$", $newemail))
      {
         $error_message = 'Email is not a valid email address. Please check and try again.';
      }
         $db = mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
         mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db);
         $sql = "SELECT username FROM ".$mysql_table." WHERE username = '".$newusername."'";
         $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
         if ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
         list($username, $password, $email, $fullname) = explode('|', trim($line));
         if ($newusername == $username)
         {
            $error_message = 'Team name already used. Please select another username.';
         }
      }
      if (empty($error_message))
      {
         $crypt_pass = md5($newpassword);
         $sql = "INSERT `".$mysql_table."` (`username`, `password`, `fullname`, `email`, `active`) VALUES ('$newusername', '$crypt_pass', '$newfullname', '$newemail', 1)";
         $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
         mysql_close($db);
         $mailto = $newemail;
         $subject = 'X';
         $message = 'X';
         $message .= "\r\nX";
         $message .= "\r\n ";
         $message .= "\r\nTeam name for the upcoming tournament: ";
         $message .= $newusername;
         $message .= "\r\nYour password: ";
         $message .= $newpassword;
         $message .= "\r\n ";
         $message .= "\r\n ";
         $message .= "\r\nX";
         $message .= "\r\nX";
         $header  = "From: X"."\r\n";
         $header .= "Reply-To: X"."\r\n";
         $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"."\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"."\r\n";
         $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion();
         mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
         header('Location: '.$success_page);
         exit;
      }
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: I will not _geev ya teh codez_

Comment: what did you mean by limit 16?

Comment: just a limit that only 16 people can register with this script

Answer (score 1):

why r u making your script complicated .just use simple counter to add 1 when ever user 
      add and when it become 16 just stop the script to add

example :

```
if(counter != 16)
{
 if (empty($error_message))
      {
     $counter++;
     $crypt_pass = md5($newpassword);
     $sql = "INSERT `".$mysql_table."` (`username`, `password`, `fullname`, `email`, `active`) VALUES ('$newusername', '$crypt_pass', '$newfullname', '$newemail', 1)";
     $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
     mysql_close($db);
     $mailto = $newemail;
     $subject = 'X';
     $message = 'X';
     $message .= "\r\nX";
     $message .= "\r\n ";
     $message .= "\r\nTeam name for the upcoming tournament: ";
     $message .= $newusername;
     $message .= "\r\nYour password: ";
     $message .= $newpassword;
     $message .= "\r\n ";
     $message .= "\r\n ";
     $message .= "\r\nX";
     $message .= "\r\nX";
     $header  = "From: X"."\r\n";
     $header .= "Reply-To: X"."\r\n";
     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"."\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"."\r\n";
     $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion();
     mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
     header('Location: '.$success_page);
     exit;
   }
 }

else
 {
   echo "not inserted";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$error_message = "";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
   $action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : '';
   $mysql_server = 'X';
   $mysql_username = 'X';
   $mysql_password = 'X';
   $mysql_database = 'X';
   $mysql_table = 'LOL';

   $success_page = 'X';
   if ($action == 'signup')
   {
      $newusername = $_POST['username'];
      $newemail = $_POST['email'];
      $newpassword = $_POST['password'];
      $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
      $newfullname = $_POST['fullname'];
      if ($newpassword != $confirmpassword)
      {
         $error_message = 'Password and Confirm Password are not the same!';
      }
      else
      if (!ereg("^[A-Za-z0-9_!@$]{1,50}$", $newusername))
      {
         $error_message = 'Team name is not valid, please check and try again!';
      }
      else
      if (!ereg("^[A-Za-z0-9_!@$]{1,50}$", $newpassword))
      {
         $error_message = 'Password is not valid, please check and try again!';
      }
      else
      if (!ereg("^.+@.+\..+$", $newemail))
      {
         $error_message = 'Email is not a valid email address. Please check and try again.';
      }
         $db = mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
         mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db);
         $sql = "SELECT username FROM ".$mysql_table." WHERE username = '".$newusername."'";
         $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
         if ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
         list($username, $password, $email, $fullname) = explode('|', trim($line));
         if ($newusername == $username)
         {
            $error_message = 'Team name already used. Please select another username.';
         }
          $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
         if ($count == 16)
         {
            $error_message = 'Team Member exceeds 16';
         }

      }
      if (empty($error_message))
      {
         $crypt_pass = md5($newpassword);
         $sql = "INSERT `".$mysql_table."` (`username`, `password`, `fullname`, `email`, `active`) VALUES ('$newusername', '$crypt_pass', '$newfullname', '$newemail', 1)";
         $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
         mysql_close($db);
         $mailto = $newemail;
         $subject = 'X';
         $message = 'X';
         $message .= "\r\nX";
         $message .= "\r\n ";
         $message .= "\r\nTeam name for the upcoming tournament: ";
         $message .= $newusername;
         $message .= "\r\nYour password: ";
         $message .= $newpassword;
         $message .= "\r\n ";
         $message .= "\r\n ";
         $message .= "\r\nX";
         $message .= "\r\nX";
         $header  = "From: X"."\r\n";
         $header .= "Reply-To: X"."\r\n";
         $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"."\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"."\r\n";
         $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion();
         mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
         header('Location: '.$success_page);
         exit;
      }
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.

Answer (score 0):

Write below code if you want to set limit for number of users.

```
$sql = "select count(*) as tot from $mysql_table";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
    $counter = $row['tot'];


if(counter != 16)
{
 if (empty($error_message))
      {
     $counter++;
     $crypt_pass = md5($newpassword);
     $sql = "INSERT `".$mysql_table."` (`username`, `password`, `fullname`, `email`, `active`) VALUES ('$newusername', '$crypt_pass', '$newfullname', '$newemail', 1)";
     $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
     mysql_close($db);
     $mailto = $newemail;
     $subject = 'X';
     $message = 'X';
     $message .= "\r\nX";
     $message .= "\r\n ";
     $message .= "\r\nTeam name for the upcoming tournament: ";
     $message .= $newusername;
     $message .= "\r\nYour password: ";
     $message .= $newpassword;
     $message .= "\r\n ";
     $message .= "\r\n ";
     $message .= "\r\nX";
     $message .= "\r\nX";
     $header  = "From: X"."\r\n";
     $header .= "Reply-To: X"."\r\n";
     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"."\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"."\r\n";
     $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion();
     mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
     header('Location: '.$success_page);
     exit;
   }
 }

else
 {
   echo "not inserted";
 }
```

Comment: well the problem is that after that i have a suceess page where all registered users are lsited from my mysql data base and there they shouldnt be listed (only the 16) and i dont want them to register couse they accept my terms and a payment so its a problem if they can register as a 17 member :s